# Jhipster Swagger Documentation showing APIs in v2/api-docs but not showing anything in swagger-ui/index.html

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, jhipster, swagger-ui

[image]

JHipster APIs showing in v2/api-docs but not showing in swagger-ui/index.html.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swagger UI Not Displaying Any Content On index.html Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30334873/swagger-ui-not-displaying-any-content-on-index-html-page)

Comment: @Alien I am facing this issue in JHipster. I checked that link, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Are you able to see the home page of your JHipster app? Did you authenticate and then use menu to see API docs?